# gnu screen: find which screen window has a given running process or variable?

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I would like to find out which of my ~50 gnu screen windows has a process running with a specific variable defined in it. For example, about a week ago, I did this:

```
id=ABC123456; ~/run_long_process $id
```

This is running in one of my ~50 gnu screen windows and it's producing a lot of STDOUT/STDERR but, other than scrolling back each of the windows or Ctrl+Z and resuming each of the windows, is there a way of finding out which one it is? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If this is Linux, you could follow a process something like this. As an example of a "long running process" I'm going to use "perl -e sleep" which just sleeps forever:

```
$ id=ABC123456; perl -e sleep $id
```

Now, we need to find the running process:

```
$ ps -Af | grep [A]BC123456
user  30579 22013  0 09:32 pts/10   00:00:00 perl -e sleep ABC123456
#           ^^^^^ parent PID
```

Now that we have the parent's PID, we can snoop in its environment, in which `screen` sets a `WINDOW` variable:

```
$ tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/22013/environ | grep WINDOW
WINDOW=3
```

Which is correct. I ran it in screen Window 3. Since this is an environment variable, there's a good chance that your task will also inherit it (depending on which flavor of `exec()` calls are used), so you can probably snoop the environment of your task as well, and find the same result.

Comment: Note that `grep [A]BC123456` is being used with `[A]` instead of `A` so that the regular expression being searched for doesn't match the `grep` process itself.  Also note that the `e` flag to `ps` (e.g. `ps -Af e`), on Linux at least, will cause it to show each process's environment, although there will be lots of variables, so you might need to use e.g. `grep --color WINDOW` so it's easier to find the relevant variable.