# How to switch to an existing vim instance from inside of screen when opening a file twice

Tags: vim, gnu-screen

When i work on many files with screen and vim, often i try to open a file already open..

I must switch manually between screen windows witch ctrl-space and press ctrl-g until i find the right window.

Is it possible to switch automatically to the right window ?..

Comment: You may want to consider using Vim's multiple buffers, tabs, and Vim's ability to act as a ['server'](http://www.rohanjain.in/yet-another-vim-productivity-post-server-client/).

Answer (score 0):

Use this /usr/local/bin/vi:

```
#!/bin/sh
VIM_PPID=$(ps -Af | grep " vim $1\$" | head -n 1 | awk '{print $3}')
if [ -n "$VIM_PPID" ] ; then
  _WINDOW=$(tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/$VIM_PPID/environ | grep ^WINDOW= | cut -f 2 -d '=')
  VIMSHELL_PPID=$(ps -Af | awk '/^[^ ]+ +'$VIM_PPID' +/{print $3}')
  MYSHELL_PPID=$(ps -Af | awk '/^[^ ]+ +'$PPID' +/{print $3}')
  if [ "$MYSHELL_PPID" = "$VIMSHELL_PPID" ] ; then
    screen -X select $_WINDOW
    exit
  fi
fi
exec /usr/bin/vim $@
```

Thanks to [this reply](https://superuser.com/questions/387026/gnu-screen-find-which-screen-window-has-a-given-running-process-or-variable)